# Symfony2 Two container service instances

Tags: php, symfony

I have an API service, for which I have two seperate accounts logins. I need to use the cloned instance of the class and call it by account name parameter

Before symfony I created a singleton of each class and store it in an array

```
array(["account1"]=>api instance, ["account2"]=>api instance)
```

The class login looks like this

```
class api
{
    protected $ses_time;
    protected $accounts = array(
                "account1"=>array(
                        "username"=>"username",
                        "password"=>"password"
                ),
                "account2"=>array(
                        "username"=>"username",
                        "password"=>"password"
                )
            );

    public function login($account)
    {
        $username = $this->accounts[$account]["username"];
        $password = $this->accounts[$account]["password"];

         $this->soap->login(
                array(
                        'username' => $username,
                        'password' => $password,
                        'session_duration' => $this->ses_time
                )
        );
    }
}
```

It would be really useful to store these in the service container, problem is if I create this as a service I can't instantiate the class twice and I can't pass **dynamic** `$account` param to the service to login.

If I change the scope to `prototype` it's not a singleton any more

Comment: You can implement a `Multiton` than, singleton for each account key

Comment: I can see how that would work instead of handling an array of singletons, but that doesn't use the symfony service container

Comment: Symfony2 container is used for `dependency management`, if you plan to inject your class in other class (`service`) than it makes sence to make it a as service else you can just use as a single class.